# Remove own submission to tag wiki (and other queues)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I have just submitted a proposal for a tag wiki and immediately realised I made a mistake, describing a wrong thing in a wrong way. Thankfully it was rejected, but I think it would be beneficial if we could remove such proposals that we placed ourselves.

That being said, I think we should be able to remove our proposals to any queues (edits, tags, votes etc)

Comment: Vote doesn't go through queue. Edit and retag (on post/wiki) go through the same suggested edit queue.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @nhahtdh. My suggestion of being able to remove own submission from the queue still stands though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your suggested edit hasn't been reviewed, you can visit the tag wiki again and change your text. If it's an initial proposal, I don't think you can withdraw it. If it's an edit of an existing post or tag wiki, if you submit the exact same markdown source as the previous revision, this withdraws your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Of course all our users are human and will make mistakes eventually — as you did, and as I have many times — but mistakes can be fixed with further editing. The important thing here is encouraging proper editing behavior.

In my mind, "proper" means getting people to do things right the first time, leading to one solid, comprehensive, high-quality edit at a time. We don't want them submitting series of minor edits in which the later ones are seen as opportunities to fix errors and omissions of the earlier ones.